# Is it possible to set ADF Trigger timeout for long running jobs using powershell

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

I have requirement to set the Azure ADF trigger timeout for Long running jobs in ADF using PowerShell. If trigger activation exceeds a certain time defined in the script then script execution should be stopped.

Comment: Do you wish to control Trigger or pipelines run timeouts?  there is an option to edit scheduled triggers with an end datetime. Please elaborate on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

​You can try below script: Run in cloud CLI or use Azure Powershell module installed on local machine.

This waits for user input

```
$rg = Read-Host "Enter ResourceGroupName"
$df = Read-Host "Enter DataFactoryName"
$tgr = Read-Host "Enter TriggerName"
$TriggerRunStartedAfter = Read-Host "Enter TriggerRunStartedAfter eg: 2021-07-01"
$TriggerRunStartedBefore = Read-Host "Enter TriggerRunStartedBefore eg: 2021-07-04"
$TimeSpan = Read-Host "TimeLimit - enter in minutes"

$ts = New-TimeSpan -Minutes $TimeSpan

$triggerDetails = Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2TriggerRun -ResourceGroupName $rg -DataFactoryName $df -TriggerName $tgr -TriggerRunStartedAfter $TriggerRunStartedAfter -TriggerRunStartedBefore $TriggerRunStartedBefore
$status = $triggerDetails.status

#Get last/latest pipelines in record

$startTime = $triggerDetails.TriggerRunTimestamp[-1]
$pipedict = $triggerDetails.TriggeredPipelines[-1]

write-host "Last run pipelines and IDs:" -foregroundcolor yellow -NoNewline; write-Host $pipedict -foregroundcolor white
$pipekey = $pipedict.keys

write-Host ""
write-Host "Pipeline names:" -foregroundcolor Yellow -NoNewline; write-Host $pipekey -foregroundcolor white

$userchoice = Read-Host "Type in a specific pipeline name or All to show details for each pipeline"

function GetStatus ($choice){


$pipeid = $pipedict[$choice]
write-Host "PipelineID:" -foregroundcolor Yellow -NoNewline; write-Host $pipeid -foregroundcolor white
$pipedetails = Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun -ResourceGroupName $rg -DataFactoryName $df -PipelineRunId $pipeid
write-Host "Status:" -foregroundcolor Yellow -NoNewline; write-Host $pipedetails.Status -foregroundcolor white
$pstatus = $pipedetails.Status
$pipelinename = $pipedetails.PipelineName
$DurationInMins = $pipedetails.DurationInMs
$lup = $pipedetails.lastUpdated
$maxTime = $startTime + $ts


if($pstatus -eq 'InProgress'){

if($lup -ge $maxTime)
{

$exceeded = NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $lup –End $maxTime
Write-Host "Pipeline running past limit. Minutes exceeded: " -NoNewline; write-Host $exceeded -foregroundcolor Red -NoNewline; write-Host "Total time: " -NoNewline; write-Host $DurationInMins -foregroundcolor Red
}
else {
write-Host "Pipeline is under limits" -foregroundcolor Green
}
}
else {
write-Host "Pipeline not Active" -foregroundcolor Green
}
}

if($userchoice -eq "all")
{
write-Host "You selected all" -foregroundcolor green
foreach ($h in $pipekey){
write-Host ""
write-Host "for  " -NoNewline; write-Host $h -foregroundcolor red
GetStatus -choice $h
}

}
else{
write-Host "choice is:" $userchoice
GetStatus -choice $userchoice
}
 
function Stop ($cstopc){

$stopdetails = Stop-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun -ResourceGroupName $rg -DataFactoryName $df -PipelineRunId $pipeid
write-Host $stopdetails
write-Host "Pipeline stopped"
$cstoptrigger = Read-Host "do you want to stop the trigger as well? Y or N"
if($cstoptrigger -eq "y"){
$stoptriggerdetails = Stop-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $rg -DataFactoryName $df -TriggerName $tgr
write-Host $stoptriggerdetails
write-Host "Trigger stopped"
}
}
 if($exceeded){
 $cstop = Read-Host "Stop pipelines? Y or N or all"
if($cstop -eq "y"){
Stop -cstopc $cstop
}
 }
 else{
write-Host ""
write-Host "bye :)"
 }
```

Or key in all details and let the script do the job (replace this bit in the beginning of above script in place of Read-Host lines)

Example:

```
#Setresource details
$rg = "v-kabhyr"
$df = "ktestdf"
$tgr = "trigger1"
$TriggerRunStartedAfter = "2021-07-01"
$TriggerRunStartedBefore = "2021-07-04"
$TimeSpan = 5
```

[image]

### Command details:

Get all data factories

```
PS /home/karthik> Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName "v-kabhyr" -Name "ktestdf"
```

The **Invoke-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline** command starts a run on the specified pipeline and returns a ID for that run.

```
PS /home/karthik> Invoke-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName "v-kabhyr" -DataFactoryName "ktestdf" -PipelineName "pipeline2"
a6219afe-766d-43a6-9b40-f3f3990196db
```

This GUID can be passed to **Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun** or **Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2ActivityRun** to obtain further details about this run.

```
PS /home/karthik> Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun -ResourceGroupName "v-kabhyr" -DataFactoryName "ktestdf" -PipelineRunId "a6219afe-766d-43a6-9b40-f3f3990196db"
```

The  **Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun**  command returns information about runs for the specified pipeline. If PipelineRunId is specified, it shows details for the run with that ID. If the PipelineRunId is not specified, then it shows information about all runs for the specified pipeline that happened between the values of LastUpdatedAfter and LastUpdatedBefore.

The **Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger** cmdlet starts a trigger in a data factory. If the trigger is in the 'Stopped' state, the cmdlet starts the trigger and it eventually invokes pipelines based on its definition. If the trigger is already in the 'Started' state, this cmdlet has no effect. If the Force parameter is specified, the cmdlet doesn't prompt before starting the trigger.

The **Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2TriggerRun** command returns detailed information about trigger runs for the specified trigger in the given timeframe.

```
PS /home/karthik> Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2TriggerRun -ResourceGroupName "v-kabhyr" -DataFactoryName "ktestdf" -TriggerName "trigger1" -TriggerRunStartedAfter "2021-07-01" -TriggerRunStartedBefore "2021-07-04"
```

The **Stop-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun** cmdlet stops a pipeline run in a data factory specified with the pieline run ID.

```
Stop-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun -ResourceGroupName "ADF" -DataFactoryName "WikiADF" -PipelineRunId b9730a13-aa12-4926-a8b3-8e3a974ab0bd

Confirm Are you sure you want to stop pipeline run 'b9730a13-aa12-4926-a8b3-8e3a974ab0bd' in data factory 'WikiADF'? [Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y

true
```

The **Stop-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger** cmdlet stops a trigger in a data factory. If the trigger is in the 'Started' state, the cmdlet stops the trigger and no longer invokes pipelines. If the trigger is already in the 'Stopped' state, this cmdlet has no effect. If the Force parameter is specified, the cmdlet doesn't prompt before stopping the trigger.

```
Stop-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName "ADF" -DataFactoryName "WikiADF" -TriggerName "ScheduledTrigger"

Confirm
Are you sure you want to stop trigger 'ScheduledTrigger' in data factory 'TestFactory'?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y
True
```